# Перестановка цифр в числе

Tags: java

подскажите пожалуйста, как посчитать и вывести все перестановки цифр в числе(
Функцию для определения факториала написал, а как написать из факториала перестановку цифр не знаю.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*
       Определение факториала числа введеного пользователем
    */
    int result = 1, n = -1;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Введите натуральное число: ");
    n = scan.nextInt();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(n);
    sb.append("!=");
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        result *= i;
        sb.append(i);
        sb.append("*");
    }
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());          
}
```

Comment: вам нужно получить все возможные числа полученные перестановкой цифр исходного числа или только их количество?

Comment: все возможные числа

Comment: Почему выводится `6!=1*2*3*4*5*6`, а не `==`?

Comment: Если введено `6`, то нужны перестановки 1,2,3,4,5,6 или результата (720), т.е. цифр 7, 2 и 0?

Comment: если ввели 6, то 1,2,3,4,5,6 и их перестановки

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець, потому что это знак факториала, а не равенства. `6! = ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void permutation(String str) {
    permutation("", str);
}

private static void permutation(String prefix, String str) {
    int n = str.length();
    if (n == 0) System.out.println(prefix);
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, n));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    permutation("12345");
}
```

Comment: это получается через статический метод, а можно это сделать, чтобы я вводил число, вычисляло факториал, и потом уже происходила перестановка цифр из факториала?